# Does cancelling an order in BTC-E carry a fee?

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, btce

I want to know when BTC-E charges it's 0.2% fee on a cancelled buy/sell order...

1. When placed but 0% completed
2. When placed but partially completed

How much are you billed in each case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fee is charged over the filled portion. Either the whole order or partial.
If an order was cancelled before a trade took place (0% filled), no fee is charged.
If an order was cancelled after a portion was already filled, the remaining part is cancelled and no fee is charged over the remaining.

Comment: referring to bittrex site
https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000199651-What-fees-does-Bittrex-charge-
Any portion of an order that has not execute, will be refunded fully upon the cancellation of the order.