# Does kraken.com charge fees when an order is cancelled?

Tags: kraken

Do you pay the fees if you order a transaction then cancel/replace it?
What if the order has been partially fulfilled before cancelling?

In other words, do you pay fees for *orders* or for *transactions*?

See [the same question for e-BTC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20356/does-cancelling-an-order-in-btc-e-carry-a-fee)

Comment: It's not a duplicate kraken != e-BTC